# How do I use a variable from Tkinter drop down menu selection in my later code?

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I have a Tkinter drop down menu and will select a name, and I want to use that name in my later code.
The "name" in the dir_path won't wait and take the values I select in Tkinter drop down menu. It will show "- empty -"

```
from tkinter import *

def name(event):
    global name
    name=name_var.get()

name = "- empty -"

window = Tk()
name_var = StringVar(window)
name_label = Label(window, text = 'Please Select Name:',font=10).place(x = 100,y = 50)  
name_var.set("Menu:")
drop_menu = OptionMenu(window,name_var,"John","Mary","Alex",command=name)
drop_menu.place(x = 400,y = 50)

dir_path ="C:\\Documents\\{name}\\*.*".format(name=name)
```

Comment: `name()` is override by the line `name = ...`, so exception will be raised when item in the option menu is changed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are formatting the dir_path string before the name has been selected in the dropdown menu. Instead, you need to only format the dir_path after the name has been selected.

Here is one way to do it:

```
from tkinter import *

def name(event):
  global name
  name = name_var.get()
  update_dir()

name = "- empty -" 

def update_dir():
  global dir_path
  dir_path = "C:\\Documents\\{name}\\*.*".format(name=name)

window = Tk()
name_var = StringVar(window)
name_label = Label(window, text='Please Select Name:',font=10).place(x = 100,y = 50)
name_var.set("Menu:")
drop_menu = OptionMenu(window,name_var,"John","Mary","Alex",command=name)
drop_menu.place(x = 400,y = 50)

update_dir() # initialize dir_path
```

Comment: Hello I tried running your code in Spyder but when print the dir_path out, the answer is "C:\Documents\- empty -\*.*" It doesn't take my input.